# iCalendar Stopped working since March 1st 2016 (Outlook)

Tags: vb.net, email, outlook, icalendar

I'm really out of words to understand this problem that I have.
I'm sending a meeting request in an email as an alternate view "text/calendar".
It worked for the last 3 years. Now, since march 1st, it does not show the .ICS file inside the outlook email. When I open the same email with my gmail account, it does show the email as intended.

This is my iCal string

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Episode Software//Email Meeting Manager//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20160112T160000Z
DTEND:20160112T170000Z
DTSTAMP:20151201T161706Z
ORGANIZER;CN=noreply@fusioncontact.ca
 :mailto:noreply@fusioncontact.ca
UID:{8802ed55-1a3a-478e-a23f-5d35ff62535c}
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;
 RSVP=TRUE;
 CN=123@episodesoft.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:123@episodesoft.com
CREATED:20151201T161706Z
DESCRIPTION:Nouveau rendez-vous avec Leetwo Metal Inc pour 2016-01-12- J.P
LAST-MODIFIED:20151201T161706Z
LOCATION:7800 Aut Transcanadienne, Pointe-Claire, H9R1C6
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Nouveau rendez-vous avec Leetwo Metal Inc pour 2016-01-12- J.P
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This is how I create the alternate view before sending the email.
`AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(m_calendarViewString, loCalendarType`)

Note that the m_calendarViewString is equal to that iCal string.

When I send this email to my gmail account, it works perfectly. It does put the appointment into my calendar and it is also selected as "Yes".

Here is a screenshot :
[image: Appointmne example]

My screenshot is in french. It says that you have a new meeting with bla bla. Yes, Maybe, No. As you can see, the "Oui" (Yes) is selected by default.

Anyone has any clue, why all of a sudden it stopped working?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give much details about your Outlook environment: have you tried with different versions of Outlook, did you upgrade recently, is your Outlook client talking to an Exchange Server or to an IMAP Server, etc... In other words, this probably has more to do with a change in your environment than with this particular date or ics request.

You can also have a look at [Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me gather all the information asked and I'll get back to you. It is at a client office and they are closed today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. They use Office 365 in a cloud so it is updating automatically. We didn't make any change in their configuration since january which is 3 months before it stopped working.