# ics attachment not showing rsvp button in outlook client

Tags: c#, email, outlook, calendar, icalendar

I am sending few emails in my code with calendar invites. While all of them show up nicely in Gmail with RSVP buttons, the same email will not show any buttons in Outlook client.

Here's my relevant code for creating ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180130T053000Z
DTEND:20180130T063000Z
DTSTAMP:20171020T054607
ORGANIZER;CN=noreply@goalenvision.com:mailto:noreply@goalenvision.com
UID:3880488702684ad0b09f08d517606797@goalenvision.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-
ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=user123@gmail.com:mailto:user123@gmail.com
CREATED:20171020T054607Z
DESCRIPTION:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Management meeting - My Company Pvt. Ltd.
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Here's how the email looks in Outlook client

[image]

Then I tried creating a meeting invitation in Google Calendar to investigate the problem further and when I received the email in Outlook client, it had RSVP buttons:

[image]

This is how the ics file from google calendar looks:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20171021T030000Z
DTEND:20171021T040000Z
DTSTAMP:20171020T025616Z
ORGANIZER;CN=user123@gmail.com:mailto:mail.user123@gmail.com
UID:0lrrf4lfm9gpiku3gmfh214q7m@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE
;CN=user123@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:user123@gmail.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
TRUE;CN=user234@gmail.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:user234@gmail.com
CREATED:20171020T025616Z
DESCRIPTION:
LAST-MODIFIED:20171020T025616Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:GoalEnvision - Google
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I am clueless as to why the email from Google Calendar contains RSVP buttons while my app generated email does not even though most of the relevant fields are same/included in both ics files. Any pointers would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The answer most likely lies not in your ics file but rather in the MIME structure that you are sending. See [Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685) for more details on how you should structure your MIME message.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly your app is not firing up a response from the recipient - the reason is the message status is set to `PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;` when it should be `PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;`