# Outlook not displaying ical RSVP buttons in email body

Tags: email, outlook, coldfusion, calendar, icalendar

Outlook 2016 or Outlook 365 is not recognizing attached ics file. The rsvp buttons are not showing in the email body but it does display correctly in gmail. I am able to download the ics file and import it into outlook.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//AroFlo PtyLtd
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzY2hlZHVsZV9pZCI6MCwic2NoZWRUe
 XBlIjoiZXZlbnQiLCJncm91cGlkIjoxLCJvcmdfaWQiOjEzNywiU1ZBUk1DT05UUk9MSUQiOjM
 xMTQ5LCJ1c2VyX2lkIjo3MTk1LCJ3b3JrcmVxdWVzdF9pZCI6MCwiZXZlbnRfaWQiOjU3MTUsI
 mFsbG9jYXRpb25faWQiOjAsImNvbnRyb2xsaW5nb3JnaWQiOjEzNywidGVtcGxhdGVfaWQiOjA
 sInRzX2dyb3VwX2lkIjowfQ.lVNWzJe1VbKsxdRJ2kCpLFUo2Wb1CqJ5Eom1nTgyewc
DTSTAMP:20180513T230757Z
DTSTART:20180514T050000Z
DTEND:20180514T073000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Bri-Tech:mailto:test@email.com
CREATED:20180513T230757Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20180513T230757Z
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:test event
DESCRIPTION:
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP
 =TRUE;CN=test user;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:test1@test.com
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
CATEGORIES:AroFlo, event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Here is how the MIME email type is constructed

```
var m = new mail();
    m.setSubject( 'event' );
    m.setTo( test@email.com );
    m.setFrom( "noreply@email.com" );
    m.addPart( type="text/calendar", body="#icalFile#");
    m.addParam( type="text/calendar", file="invite.ics", content="#icalFile#");
    m.send();
```

Comment: Try creating an event in Outlook 2016 and export ics file. Then check for differences, you might get some clues. I think I have faced an issue like this. Not sure how I fixed it. It was more of a trial and error thing.

Comment: My `prodid` is `//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 15.0 MIMEDIR//EN`. But  I don't think that should make a difference. But you can try that.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the email MIME type wasn't added correctly. The code below now displays the RSVP buttons correctly.

In ColdFusion addParam() type can set more than one parameter.

```
m.addParam( type="text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST;"
           , file="invite.ics"
           , content="#icalFile#");
```