# Outlook doesn't show appointment directly

Tags: outlook, icalendar

I'm using ABAP in SAP to generate an appointment in .ics Format and Mail this. If I open Outlook the Appointment is always an E-Mail which has the appointment as attachment. But I want the appointment to be direct identified by outlook, so that I can react with "Accept" "Reject" etc. The Image below shows the E-Mail which is generated with the ICS Event Content. If I use Googlemail it works. Someone has an idea? I'm missing the RSVP Buttons[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to save any appointment item in Outlook manually using the .ics file format. Then try to open that file from a hard drive. If it is opened correctly you just need to find the missed part/difference between two .ics files (generated by Outlook and yours).

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably lies in MIME structure of the email that you are sending, not in the ics file itself. See [Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685)