# ics file attchment not showing calender in yahoo and outlook.live

Tags: outlook, gmail, icalendar, yahoo

I have sent ics file as attachment in email. it is showing rsvp buttons and showing like in below attachment for gmail and adding event directly to calendar. [image]

But same ics file i have sent to yahoo and outlook.live. ics file showing just as attachment but not showing calendar like gmail. in yahoo mail calender section continuously loading like below screen.
[image]

Here is my ics file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20190612T103000Z
DTEND:20190612T113000Z
DTSTAMP:20190612T101341Z
ORGANIZER;CN=murali.krishna@mydomai.com:mailto:murali.krishna@mydomai.com
UID:29b88vglogjev1r59qjqd0g811@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE
 ;CN=murali.krishna@mydomai.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:murali.krishna@mydomai
 .com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=muralibobby@mydomai.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:muralibobby@mydomai
 .com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=muralibobb@yahoo.com;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:muralibobb@yah
 oo.com
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-OWNERAPPTID:-287760219
CREATED:20190612T101337Z
DESCRIPTION:-::~:~::~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~
 :~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~::~:~::-\nPlease do not edit this section of the descriptio
 n.\n\nThis event has a video call.\nJoin: https://meet.google.com/bis-vec-
 fgg\n+1 503-908-2281 PIN: 24553883#\n\nView your event at https://www.goog
 le.com/calendar/event?action=VIEW&eid=MjliODZ2xvZ2pldjFyNTlxanFkMGc4MTEgb
 XVyYWxpYm9iYnkyMDE1QHlhaG9vLmNvbQ&tok=MjYjbXVyYWxpLmtyaXNobmFAbmVvYnJpYy5jb
 21hNDFjNzg4OTlmMjJmOWUxY2U0MDE2OWE3OTc0MTM2MTE2YTY3OTky&ctz=Asia%2FKolkata&
 hl=en&es=1.\n-::~:~::~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:
 ~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~:~::~:~::-
LAST-MODIFIED:20190612T101337Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:MyInvitation
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Please let me know what tags needs to send to show calender with rsvp buttons in yahoo/outlook.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably with the MIME (email) structure that you are using, not with the ics itself. See [Multipart email with text and calendar: Outlook doesn't recognize ics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523861/multipart-email-with-text-and-calendar-outlook-doesnt-recognize-ics/19535685#19535685)